# How to prevent the "overflow" of multiply several small numbers?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list with x very small numbers and want to create the product of them. I only want to use pure Python or/and numpy.

```
      # List A with x very small numbers 
      A =[1.20223398e-072 1.53678559e-067 6.04813112e-041 3.26046833e-104
      3.09114525e-048 7.65394632e-118 4.58886892e-209 7.02220200e-044
      3.40963578e-085 2.79721084e-060 6.99320974e-052 7.65701921e-039
      3.05321642e-103 2.33360119e-050 2.92905105e-044 5.13970623e-044
      6.46863409e-180 1.78254565e-177 6.26061488e-068 5.86281346e-043]

      #creating the product of all elements in A
      np.prod(A)
```

Output:

> 0.0

And this is a problem, maybe an overflow?!
What have I tried?

1. I tried to do this in a loop => very bad 
   running time and did not work

Input:

> ```
> prod = 1
> for i in A):
>     prod = prod * A
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> 0.0

2. I tried to sort by amount and then multiply from the array always the first and last, then second and penultimate, third and third last, ....
   => Did not work ether 
   Input:

> ```
> prod = 1
> A.sort()
> for i in range(len(A)):
>     prod = prod * (A[i]*A[-i-1])
> ```

Output:

> 0.0

Do any one has an idea how to solve this problem?

Best regards
Christian

Comment: You should add your code, what have you tried, together with the output and your expected output. Asking for a suggestion like the one you are asking might be seen as off-topic or lacking a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: @CeliusStingher Hi, is it better now?

Comment: Yes, much better! You even got your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying floating point storage is not large enough to hold so small numbers, especially their product, which grows smaller the more you multiply.

```
>>> A[0]*A[1]               
1.8475758562723483e-139
>>> A[0]*A[1]*A[2]          
1.1174381032881437e-179
>>> A[0]*A[1]*A[2]*A[3]     
3.6433715465062613e-283
>>> A[0]*A[1]*A[2]*A[3]*A[4]
0.0
```

However, with these specific numbers, the product actually fits in a `np.float128` type:

```
>>> np.prod(A, dtype=np.float128)
6.439950307032109978e-1637
```

Of course, this just moves the goal post: Multiplying other numbers could again give you a zero.

An alternative is to use the `decimal` module in Python, which will give you the most flexibility in dealing with exact numbers. It's much slower than IEEE floats, though, but should work:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> B = [decimal.Decimal(x) for x in A]
>>> B[0]*B[1]
Decimal('1.847575856272348173712320037E-139')
>>> B[0]*B[1]*B[2]
Decimal('1.117438103288143607857271302E-179')
>>> B[0]*B[1]*B[2]*B[3]
Decimal('3.643371546506261078793026112E-283')
>>> B[0]*B[1]*B[2]*B[3]*B[4]
Decimal('1.126219064996798351280705310E-330')
```

Comment: Hi! I tried decimal and it works, but i can not use it, that's the problem:) But i will test dtype=np.float64

Comment: I updated with `dtype=np.float128` and for _these_ numbers it works, but it could result in zero again for other numbers.